# Cant add div underneath Relative Div with stacked pngs

Tags: html, css-position, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and have a Relative Div that contains stacked pngs to add different layers of images for a configurator I'm building. My problem is I need to add another div below that Relative div but it ends up being on top of the Relative div as well. The images are all the same size within the relative div but change sizes based on which configurator is chosen. How do I get around this?

```
     <div class="row parent">
                        <div id="boat-images" class="card-img-overlay">

                            <div id="base-images" class="">
                                <img id="base" src="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="top-images" class="">
                            <img id="top" src="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                        </div>
                        <div id="stripe-images" class=""><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE1" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE1" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE2" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE2" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE3" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE3" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE4" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE4" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE7" style="display: none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE7" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="STRIPE13" style="display: none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"><img crossorigin="anonymous" id="selected-STRIPE13" style="display:none;" src="" "="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image"></div>
                        <div id="options-images" class="">
                            <img id="platform" src="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="engine" src="" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="BOWRAIL" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="RUBRAIL_PAINTED" src="" style="display:none" alt="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="RUBRAIL" src="" alt="" style="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="TOPT_FLAG" src="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="ENTERTAINMENT_TBL" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="VHF" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="OUTRIGGERS" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="ROD_HOLDERS" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="SPORT_STATION" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="WINDSHIELD_FULLGLASS" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="FLAGSTAFF" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="LOGO" src="" alt="" style="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="ACCESSORIES" src="" alt="" style="" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                            <img id="BLACK-TRIM" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="img-fluid child-image " crossorigin="anonymous">
                        </div>
                        <div id="stripe-highlight-images" class=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center center-container" id="report-center-splotch"><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(135, 117, 99);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 1</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Latte Metallic</h6></div></div></div><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 2</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Cosmic Black Metallic</h6></div></div></div><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(228, 209, 187);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 3</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Morning Sand Metallic</h6></div></div></div><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(235, 234, 216);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 4</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Cashmere Metallic</h6></div></div></div><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 7</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Cosmic Black Metallic</h6></div></div></div><div class="square"><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center round-splotch" style="background-color:rgb(235, 234, 216);"></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center font-weight-bolder"><p style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 0.775em;"><strong>Stripe 13</strong></p></div></div><div class="col-12"><div class="text-center text-font"><h6 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 0.675em;">Cashmere Metallic</h6></div></div></div></div>
                    </div>
```

The div doesn't seem to expand and fill the whole size of the relative div on the page either. I'm assuming this is normal for a div as well?

I'm not sure what the proper approach is for this. Any help would be appreciated.